# Как "ускорить" создание Json файла

Tags: json, php

Добрый день.
Есть запрос к БД, который мне надо перевести в формат JSON.
Я извращаюсь с циклами и добавлением знаков `{}[];,`. В файле несколько вложений, и, капец, уже запутался. Есть ли какой-нибудь инструмент на php, чтобы ускорить это всё?
Спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Example  
http://vstarkov.ru/markdown-basics/#text-formatting
http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks
https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lines
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p
http://hashcode.ru/questions/361687#comment-361691

Answer (score 2):

```
json_encode
```

изучаем)

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Я как раз вот читаю. До этого тупил нереально, подрисовывая в цикле {}